# WordPress - remove capabilities based on user id

Tags: php, wordpress

I current have this code written:

```
add_action( 'init', 'hide_user_caps' );
function hide_user_caps() {
    $user_id = 1;
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user->remove_cap( 'edit_posts' );
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be doing anything. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specifically deny a capability from a user (not a role), you need to use the [`add_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/add_cap/)*[1]* method and specify that the `$grant` parameter is false. *[2]*.

```
$user_id = 1;
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->add_cap( 'edit_posts', false );
```

---

- *[1]: [`WP_User::add_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/add_cap/)*
- *[2]: [The answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/260777)*

Comment: Thank you for that, when would you use remove_cap then? Just curious..

Comment: @cjblue When you want to delete from within a role.